# Making a cookie available to a sibling domain with Ember

Tags: javascript, cookies, ember.js

In an Ember app, we set cookies using `ember-cookie`. At the moment, the `userToken` cookie is available to `www.example.com` only. I need to make it available to `api.example.com` as well and expected below code to work: Even if `domain` (which is actually set through an environment variable) starts with "www", the cookie should be set one level higher (and thus be available to the `api` subdomain as well).

```
set cookieToken(token) {
  let domain = 'www.example.com';

  // Share with main domain (and API subdomain) even if host is www subdomain
  if (domain.startsWith('www')) {
    const apiSubdomain = domain.replace(/^www/, '');
    this.cookies.write('userToken', JSON.stringify(token), { path: '/', apiSubdomain })
  }
}
```

This approach failed, however:

- expected domain: .example.com
- observed domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I also tried setting the cookie for `api.example.com` explicitly:

```
if (domain.startsWith('www')) {
  const apiSubdomain = domain.replace(/^www/, 'api');
  this.cookies.write('userToken', JSON.stringify(token), { path: '/', apiSubdomain })
}
```

The outcome was the same:

- expected domain: api.example.com
- observed domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

What can I do to make this cookie accesible for both subdomains?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I didn't specify the `domain` key in the options hash. The following code would have worked because `domain` is equivalent to `domain: domain`:

```
this.cookies.write('userToken', JSON.stringify(token), { path: '/', domain })
```

In my case, however, I named the variable differently, so I need to specify the key explicitly:

```
this.cookies.write('userToken', JSON.stringify(token), { path: '/', domain: apiSubdomain })
```